# React.js and arrow functions vs normal functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I was working on a react.js app and I initially used the arrow function which worked, but then just out of curiosity I decided to try the normal function and the normal function didn't work. I think that they both should output the same thing, what is going wrong?

```
handleChange = event => this.setState({init: event.target.value})

handleChange(event){
  this.setState({init: event.target.value})
}
```

Comment: check the es version you are using.According to that you should use the syntax.If the necessary module missing it will gives and error

Answer (score 16):

Arrow functions and normal function **are not equivalent**.

Here is the difference:

1. Arrow function **do not** have their own binding of `this`, so your `this.setState` refer to the `YourClass.setState`.
2. Using normal function, you need to bind it to the class to obtain Class's `this` reference. So when you call `this.setState` actually it refer to `YourFunction.setState()`.

Sample Code

```
class FancyComponent extends Component {
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ event }) // `this` is instance of handleChange
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ event }) // `this` is instance of FancyComponent
    }
}
```