# Not able to submit form - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From my landing page I am sending function to my search bar page.

**LandingPage.js**

```
export default class LandingPage extends React.Component {

   onSearchSubmit(term){
    console.log(term);
   }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <div><SearchBar onSubmit = {this.onSearchSubmit} /></div>
            </div>
            ......
```

**SearchBar.js**

```
export default class SearchBar extends React.Component{

    state = {term: ''};

    onFormSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.props.onSubmit(this.state.term);
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container">

                    <div className="searchBar mt-5">
                        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="search">Image search</label>
                                <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    className="form-control" 
                                    placeholder="Search..." 
                                    value = {this.state.term}
                                    onChange={e => this.setState({term: e.target.value})}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My landing page (in this case parent) is on `http://localhost:3000/` and when I type something in search bar on landing page it works just fine.

But when I go to `http://localhost:3000/searchbar` and type there I get following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.onSubmit is not a function
```

**UPDATE:**

I have tried with adding binding and it's still not working.
It works if I search the search bar on landing page like this.

[image]

But my question is if I go to only search bar page which is on `http://localhost:3000/searchbar`

[image]

separate of landing page which is on `http://localhost:3000/` can I send data back?

I am still getting same error.

My question is is this even possible with ReactJS to send data back to parent page from child page on different URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Solution that worked for me was making my `App.js` parent and `LandingPage.js` and `SearchBar.js` pages as child pages.

**App.js** looked like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(

    <div>
      <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={Admin}/>
      <Route path="/posts" component={Post} />
      <Route path="/categories" component={Categories} />
      <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
      <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />

      <Route path="/weatherapp" component={weatherApp} />
      <Route path="/bar" component={SearchBar}/>
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

To make `App.js` as parent have changed it to look like this:

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        articalName: "Landing page"
    };

}

onSearchSubmit = term => {
  console.log(term);
}


  render(){
    return(

    <div>
      <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={ () => 
        <Admin 
          title={this.state.articalName}

          />}  
      />
      <Route path="/posts" component={Post} />
      <Route path="/categories" component={Categories} />
      <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
      <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />

      <Route path="/weatherapp" component={weatherApp} />
      <Route path="/bar" component={ () => 
        <SearchBar 
          onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit}

          />}  
         />
    </div>
  )
  }
}
```

I used routes to send my data from parent to child.

So basically structure of my app looks like this now:

[image]

Instead of what it looked like before:

[image]

I have stored state in a parent component and pass down the state to child components. This example uses React Router 4. I wanted to use only ReactJs but I guess good solution would be also using Redux.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue related to scope of `this` keyword in event callbacks. To overcome this you need to bind your functions in your component's constructor. Check official documents at React website: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

You can solve your problem by adding following binding in your constructor.

```
// This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
```

Comment: If this is the cause the OP is using a class field in the other component so he should probably use it here too instead of adding a constructor (for consistency).

Comment: @Andy I didn't get what you mean use it here ?

Comment: See Dhaval's answer.

Comment: @user9347049 How do you do routing stuff? I need to see the component for /searchbar page.

Answer (score 2):

issue is with your onSearchSubmit scope.

for that you have 2 options.

> bind onSearchSubmit function in constructor like this

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onSearchSubmit = this.onSearchSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

> second option without using scope binding : change onSearchSubmit to
>   arrow function.

```
export default class LandingPage extends React.Component {

  onSearchSubmit = term => {
    console.log(term);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div><SearchBar onSubmit = {this.onSearchSubmit} /></div>
        </div>
        ......
```

Comment: Hi, can you please check update on my question... tnx

Answer (score 1):

To preserve your style, make your onSearchSubmit function an arrow function:

```
  onSearchSubmit = term => {
    console.log(term);
  }
```

Here you can find why should you use an arrow function there or what is the alternative (binding `this`):
[React.js and arrow functions vs normal functions [duplicate]
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51778556/11130354)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and I am still getting same error... I wander is it even possible to do so as I wrote in my update on my question.

Comment: How does your routing look like?
On `/searchbar` route do you pass the SerachBar component an onSubmit handler function? And could you post your error messages?

Comment: I have found solution that worked for me. I restructured my app and used routing to pass data between my components. Please check it. :) I have used fat arrow function but binding wasn't necessary.